# Argv functions vs. LuaJIT FFI's vararg

Tags: optimization, lua, ffi, luajit

Is there a more effecient way to handle argv functions than this?

```
ffi.cdef [[ 
  void fooArgv(int argc, const char ** argv, const size_t * argvlen); 
]]

local foo = function(...)
  local nargs = select("#", ...)
  local argv = { }
  local argvlen = { }

  for i = 1, nargs do
    local v = tostring( (select(i, ...)) )
    argv[i] = v
    argvlen[i] = #v
  end

  return ffi.C.fooArgv(
      nargs,
      ffi.new("const char * [" .. nargs .. "]", argv),
      ffi.new("const size_t [" .. nargs .. "]", argvlen)
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: A side note. Using the long string format `[[ ]]` in the last `ffi.new` lines instead of the simpler `" "` or `' '` forms contribute to obfuscate the code.

Comment: That is a matter of taste, personal preference and coding guidelines that are in effect for a given piece of code. But I see your point. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `foo` is called a lot of times, you can easily optimize the bottom part of the function. Calling `ffi.new` with a string argument forces LuaJIT to run its C parser every time, which is sub-optimal. The function `ffi.typeof` can create a *constructor* for a given type that is used then instead of `ffi.new`.

Also, I think that using the `select` function in a loop is slower that creating an array and indexing from it. I am not sure of this.

So here is my proposed version:

```
ffi.cdef [[ 
  void fooArgv(int argc, const char ** argv, const size_t * argvlen); 
]]

local argv_type = ffi.typeof("const char* [?]")
local argvlen_type = ffi.typeof("const size_t [?]")

local foo = function(...)
  local nargs = select("#", ...)
  local argv = { ... }
  local argvlen = { }

  for i = 1, nargs do
    local v = tostring( argv[i] )
    argv[i] = v
    argvlen[i] = #v
  end

  return ffi.C.fooArgv(
      nargs,
      argv_type(nargs, argv),
      argvlen_type(nargs, argvlen)
    )
end
```

Comment: Interesting... I missed that `[?]` thing (knew about `[$]`). Plan to re-check the docs and do some micro-benchmarking tomorrow. Will get back with info. Thanks!

Comment: Aha, that's just a variable length array. Neat.

Comment: Regarding select vs. table: select is *faster*: https://github.com/agladysh/luamarca/commit/726d4b0305dff87b98bda104ae181704ea2b48d8